# Difference between a=b and b=a, foreach loop

Tags: java, loops, foreach

I made a small program which outputs a person with highest height/weight ratio. I made a foreach loop:

```
public Person highestDivideRating() {
    if(this.members.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Person highestSoFar = this.members.get(0);

    for(Person person : this.members) {
        if(person.divide() > highestSoFar.divide()) {
            highestSoFar = person;
            //person = highestSoFar;
        }

    }
    return highestSoFar;
}
```

`highestSoFar = person;` This outputs a person with highest ratio.

`person = highestSoFar;` This outputs first person.

Could someone explain me this? For me it should be the same.

Comment: please go study some basics and you could find your answer

Comment: Since when 
set value A equals to value B is the same as
set value B equals to value A ;)

Comment: "`highestSoFar = person;` This outputs a person with highest ratio." No it doesn't. It changes the value of `highestSoFar`

Comment: person = highestSofar . If you look up a bit you will actually see that highestSoFar = this.members.get(0). Therefore it will always be first person.

Comment: "For me it should be the same." <- how would that work? Think about `int a=0; int b=1; a=b;` and `int a=0; int b=1; b=a;`<- If `a=b` would be the same as `b=a` and both these codes would be identical what values would a and b have after that operation? 0 or 1? Assignment operations cannot be commutative.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign `highestSoFar` to `person`, `highestSoFar` is never changed inside the loop, and keeps referring to its initial value - `this.members.get(0)`.

If you assign `person` to `highestSoFar`, as you should, your loop finds the person with the highest `divide()`.

Comment: Is it possible to modify an item in a collection during iteration with a for-statement in Java? In C# this isn't possible, so 'person = highestSoFar' would result in an exception "Can not assign because it's iteration variable / An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged.". Same for Java?

Comment: @CasparKleijne as Java doesn't have pointers/references `person = highestSoFar` would have no effect on the original List at all. (it would let the local variable person point at another object but leave the original reference in the list untouched)

Answer (score 0):

`a = b` is not same as `b = a` in java.

From [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) :

> One of the most common operators that you'll encounter is the simple
>   assignment operator "=".
>   it assigns the value on its right to the operand on its left.

So when you do :

`a = b; //it means b's value is assigned to a`

and when you do :

`b = a; //it means a's value is assigned to b`

So now you can again go through your code to understand what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you make put first value in your `highestSoFar` variable and don't modify this variable after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 parts in the affectation (left part and right part).

In the affectation, the left part value will be lose and will receive the value of the right part. The right part will not change.

**a = b** ==> replace the content of **a** by **b**. **b** will not change and **a** will.

**b = a** ==> replace the content of **b** by **a**. **a** will not change and **b** will.